# What does 4 beeps mean when you boot up your laptop?

Tags: laptop

My laptop is by Dell. I looked up beep error codes on their site and the page I found (it no longer exists) only mentioned 3 beep codes but my computer is making 4 beeps. So perhaps this means something else.

What does 4 beeps mean when you turn on your computer? I googled more and I've seen it mention system timer (I have no idea what that means or how to fix it) and forums that mention to try and take out RAM.

Any ideas?

-edit1- I took out the RAM, now I get 2 beeps and looking that up failed.

-edit2- I put one RAM stick back in and it worked. I put both back in and it still worked?? Well... it works now and has been for the last 2 hours. These beeps may be "Power On System Test (POST)" code. I am unsure though.

Comment: The beep codes you linked to were for the GX620 (a desktop); there will be an equivalent page for your model of laptop, which should cover what 4 beeps stands for. Sorry, can't be any more specific as you don't state the laptop model.

Comment: -1 I am going to start down voting questions that can only be answered if the OP posts the exact make and model number and does not do so.

Comment: @Moab: The POST codes are not computer specific... I never heard of POST codes until i googled the problem this morning

Comment: @acidzombie24 they are specific on a Dell, HP, etc. You never heard of  post codes but know they are not specific?

Comment: @acidzombie24: What BIOS does your laptop have? Are the beeps equally long?

Comment: POST codes **are** computer specific, or more precisely, each motherboard manufacturers had their own POST code. The reason dell doesn't list the 4 beep code in the page you're referring to is because there is no 4 beep code in that particular model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POST AMI BIOS beep codes include, "4 beeps: Motherboard timer not operational (check all PSU to MB connectors seated)"; "2 beeps: Parity error in base memory (first 64 KiB block)" See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beep_codes

But you will want to check your laptop manual (or edit your post to include laptop model and have us do that) to find the exact answer as the beep codes often are specific for laptop manufacturers. If you don't have the manual right now, you can take a look at the http://www.dell.com Dell official website, the section "drivers and downloads" asks your model number and shows you a list of drivers and manuals for the product.

Answer (score 1):

You maybe fried your RAM. Happened to me after spilling water on keyboard. Dried it all out, 4 beeps on start up.

Indeed, Dell has deleted its beep error code translation pages.